# How do I make an existing expand/collapse JS menu accessible by setting aria-expanded and aria-hidden attributes programmatically?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I am not proficient in JS but I am hoping someone can show me how to make an existing expand/collapse JS menu accessible by setting aria-expanded and aria-hidden attributes programmatically to the existing JS. Note: I cannot edit the menu's HTML. Thank you.

```
// JavaScript Document 
imgout=new Image(9,9);
imgin=new Image(9,9);

/////////////////BEGIN USER EDITABLE///////////////////////////////
    imgout.src="images/u.gif";
    imgin.src="images/d.gif";
///////////////END USER EDITABLE///////////////////////////////////
//this switches expand collapse icons
function filter(imagename,objectsrc){
    if (document.images){
        document.images[imagename].src=eval(objectsrc+".src");
    }
}
//show OR hide funtion depends on if element is shown or hidden
function shoh(id) { 

    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none"){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            filter(("img"+id),'imgin');         
        } else {
            filter(("img"+id),'imgout');
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';         
        }   
    } else { 
        if (document.layers) {  
            if (document.id.display == "none"){
                document.id.display = 'block';
                filter(("img"+id),'imgin');
            } else {
                filter(("img"+id),'imgout');    
                document.id.display = 'none';
            }
        } else {
            if (document.all.id.style.visibility == "none"){
                document.all.id.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                filter(("img"+id),'imgout');
                document.all.id.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}

<!-- HTML Source -->
<div class="box" >
  <div class="boxHead">
    <h2><a href="index.php">First Responders</a></h2>
  </div>
  <ul class="sidebarNav">
    <li class="order"><a href="order.html">Order FREE Materials</a></li>
    <li class="safetyinfo"><a href="safety/index.html">Advanced Safety Info</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="safety/overhead.html" class="overhead">Overhead Line Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety/downed.html" class="downed">Downed Power lines</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety/carpole.html" class="carpole">Car/Pole Accidents</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety/substation.html" class="substation">Substation Fires</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="training"><a href="presentation/index.html">Presentation  Tools</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely link and advice.

Comment: The document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true"); and document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true"); should work as long as the variable ‘id’ contains a valid HTML element ID.

Unfortunately, in the HTML, that doesn’t seem to be the case. Although it does appear that the shoh function takes an ID argument, so I still don’t know what’s going on there.

Comment: On further inspection I'm not convinced you've posted code for a menu. It references images. It looks like someone's show/hide utility function. Are you sure your menu uses JavaScript? It could be CSS-only. Got a link to share?

Comment: Sorry, this is a client's script behind a secure login. I need to work with their existing JS to add aria-expanded and aria-hidden attributes to better support assistive technologies.

Comment: Please, don't put code in comments. That's not good for anyone. Update your question with relevant information and format it properly.